# Is there a debugger tool that shows the value of a variable?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am looking for a debugger tool that helps me find what causes the error in my program?

Usually to debug I use the **print(variable) function** to see what the value of a certain variable is at a given time. Hence I can see where and when something goes wrong.
However, this takes way too long if the program is a little longer.

I wish there was tool which would show the value of a variable when I move the mouse to that variable. Instead, I always have to go into the code and use the print function in multiple place and run the program multiple times.

Example:

```
y = "otito"
y = list(y)
del y[2] ###show me the new value of y when mouse over y = "otto"###
```

Is there something like this out there?

IF NOT

How do you guys go about to check the value of variables at certain times?

Comment: Python has a built-in text mode debugger: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Pycharm has built-in debugging capabilities. First, set the breakpoint at the point (line) you would like to see the variable. In your case that would have to be after the `del y[2]` line, as this is the point that the `del` would have effect:

y = "otito"
y = list(y)
del y[2] 
y             # <- set the Breakpoint at this line, by just clicking right of the number line in Pycharm

Then, run your program with `Run -> Debug` and it will stop at the breakpoint and show you all of the variables, including `y`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had to add another line to see the value of list y after del y[2] but that exactly what I was looking for.